# Qemu: trace MMU operation

Tags: arm, qemu, emulation

Currently I'm trying to run **qemu-system-arm** for **armv7** architecture, do some initial setup for paging and then enable MMU.

I run qemu with gdb stub and connect to it then with gdb.

I must have screwed something up with translation tables/registers/etc., the thing is the minute I set MMU-enable bit in control register, gdb can't fetch data from memory anymore: after **ni** command which executes mmu-enable instruction it doesn't fetch next command and I can't access memory.

Is there any way to look what happens inside Qemu's MMU? Where it takes translation tables from, what calculates etc.

Or should I just recompile it with my additional debug output?

Comment: Translation tables address is stored in ttrb0/1 registers. What mmu do with this tables is explained in armv7 reference manual

Comment: @AlexHoppus I couldn't agree more, but I'd like to check my descriptors and that's where a kind of debugging output would be useful. Anyway I've already sorted qemu sources out and added my own logs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to trace this without modifying QEMU's sources yourself to add debugging output. This is a specific case of a more general tendency, which is that QEMU's design and approach is largely "run correct code quickly", not to provide detailed introspection into the behaviour of possibly buggy guests. Sometimes, as in this case, there's a nice easy location to add your own debug printing; sometimes, as in the fairly common desire to print all the memory accesses made by the guest, there is nowhere in the C code where tracing can be put to catch all accesses.

Answer (score 5):

> No, there's no way to trace this without modifying QEMU's sources yourself

So I did. For ARM architecture, the relevant code is found in ***target-arm/helper.c*** - ***get_phys_addr**** functions.

Answer (score 0):

When I used QEMU for debugging VM issues in an operating system kernel that I had built with a colleague, I ended up connecting GDB to debug QEMU instead (instead of debugging the guest process inside QEMU).

You can place breakpoints on the MMU table walking function and step through it.